# htaccess prevent host redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am using a free host server to host my site and every is fine except that every so often my host will redirect my site and I am unable to access my site until the redirect is removed (usually around 30 minutes after it is first redirected). Is there any way that I can stop my host from redirecting my site using htaccess or just force the redirect back to my site (although, this is will probably cause a redirect loop)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, their redirect will always have a higher precedence than any .htaccess override.